# Visual Studio Code find selected text in files

Tags: visual-studio-code, findinfiles

In Visual Studio Code:

I would like to: select text in editor, press hotkey "for find in files", press return:

result: find all instances of selected text in files

(So I would need the currently selected text copy pasted into the search input field)

Comment: `ctrl+shift+f` ?

Answer (score 0):

The default keybinding for search ctrl+shift+f works - it uses the command:
"-workbench.action.findInFilesWithSelectedText"

I had a custom key binding and mapped to
    "command": "-workbench.action.findInFiles"

Comment: This comment makes it sound like workbench.action.findInFilesWithSelectedText was removed in 2018: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44609