# How to Find Selection in Files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Cmd-E enters the word under the cursor into the File search box. Is there anything similar for the *Find in Files* multiple search box?

I'd like to put the cursor on a word, hit a key combination, and have the Find in Files pane opened and with the word already filled in.

A previous answer [Visual Studio Code find selected text in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640686/visual-studio-code-find-selected-text-in-files) suggests a command that appears to have been removed: `workbench.action.findInFilesWithSelectedText`

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+shift+f?

Comment: Wow! Ctrl-D and then Ctrl+Shift+F works. I would never have guessed.

Do you know why Ctrl-F has Ctrl-E, but Ctrl-Shift-F has no equivalent?

Comment: I'll try to get in the habit of using Ctrl-D instead of Ctrl-E since Ctrl-D works consistently with both Ctrl-F and Ctrl-Shift-F. Thank you!

Comment: Ctrl+D is supposed to do something very different.  Ctrl+F seeds the find widget, and Ctrl+Shift+F seeds the search pane (aka find in files).  You shouldn't have to do Ctrl+D for this.

Comment: @Mark you're right, and I never noticed. Old habits die hard. So I guess Ctrl-E is useless nowadays?

Comment: Ctrl+E does the same as Ctrl+P now  - opens the quickPanel for files.

Comment: On my system, the default bindings map Cmd+E to `actions.findWithSelection`, which now appears to be completely redundant? (sorry for being sloppy with 'Cmd' vs 'Ctrl') Also I appear to have an extension which prevents Ctrl+Shift+F from seeding the search pane. It works as you say when I start with --disable-extensions. More investigation to do!

Comment: Ah, found my source of confusion: the Find widget always gets seeded when I hit Cmd-F. The Find in Files panel only gets seeded if it's already blank. I would expect both would either always seed, or only seed when blank.

Comment: Ah, here's the answer: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88160

Comment: Restarting with extensions disabled also clears the search box... so I spent quite some time trying to figure out which extension was causing the issue.  :)